# How does ruby on rails know what to put in @params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rhomobile

What should I do in my html page to get the id/value into the @params instance in a controller method on a POST?  Ie:

```
<input type='hidden' id='qgroup' value='blahDeBlah'/>
```

How would I get the value of id='qgroup' into the @params with the right id as the key?

Comment: It needs a `name=` attribute -- then it will be in `params`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the name of the field to use it from the params.

`<input type='hidden' name='qgroup' id='qgroup' value='blahDeBlah'/>`